# ArrayList.Item property not found. Using NET Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, arraylist

For some reason Visual Studio has every property and method of ArrayList except the Item property(it will not appear in the auto complete box). It will not compile when I use it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Item` property in C# is accessible through the square brackets operator. For example, if the documentation for [`List<T>` says that a class exposes property `Item` that takes an `int` and returns a `T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx). You can use it like this:

```
var res = myList[123];
```